# Why did i get Status Code: 405; Method Not Allowed after trying to execute the delete action?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

ASP.NET Core 5.0, EF Core 5.0
My action :

```
[HttpPost("id")]
    public IActionResult DeleteEquipment(int id)
    {
        repository.DeleteEquipment(id);
        return View("WorkoutDB");
    }
```

My ef method:

```
    public void DeleteEquipment(int Id)
    {
        _context.Remove(new Equipment() { EquipmentId = Id });
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

My button from partial view:

```
<input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("DeleteEquipment", "Admin", item.EquipmentId)'" /
```

I don't know is it normal code or not, i am newbie, but i spent 4 hours and couldn't get the result.
Thanks for you attention!

**UPD:**
I changed my button

```
<td>
       <form asp-action="DeleteEquipment" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="EquipmentId" value="@item.EquipmentId" />
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
             Delete
          </button>
       </form>
 </td>
```

But its still not working. I cant bind correct value to EquipmentId. Always  0 value. Why?

Comment: When you say "ASP.NET 5, EF 5" - do you mean the "old, classic, full" .NET framework (up to and including .NET 4.8 - running ASP.NET MVC 5 and EF "classic" 5) - or are you just unclear and really mean ASP.NET **Core** 5 and EF **Core** 5 ?? Please be more precise in what you're using! It can definitely make a difference! Your tags aren't helpfu, either - referencing both worlds.....

Comment: Thanks! I will fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

location.href='@Url.Action("DeleteEquipment", "Admin", item.EquipmentId)' cause browser to redirect user to new url. Redirect cause GET Request but your DeleteEquipment method has HttpPost attribute.

Replace

```
[HttpPost("id")]
```

with

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
```

As @mason mentioned if you need to call your api with POST Request you need to use form.

```
<form asp-action="DeleteEquipment" asp-controller="Admin" asp-route-id="@item.EquipmentId">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

Comment: Generally an action method for deleting shouldn't be reached with a GET request. A DELETE method is more appropriate, or in a pinch with a POST request and following the [Post-Redirect-Get pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). I'm not saying it's possible to use a GET, but it leads to weird behavior (like remembering the GET request in browser history, a refresh causing it to re-delete etc).

Comment: can you check my upd)

Comment: @VladBondarenko in your DeleteEquipment method you receive id not EquipmentId. So you need to change your input hidden name from EquipmentId to id

Comment: Now i am going to gym without any remorse. Im very grateful

Comment: @VladBondarenko You're welcome. It would be apritiated if my answer helped you mark it as accepted and vote it up ;)

Comment: @MrMoeinM marked but can't vote cuz dont have 15 point of reputation) joined today